# Returning the remaining string in strtok function?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, strtok, function-definition

I am writing my own `strtok` function. How do I make it so that it will return the remaining string as an output parameter?

Here is what I made so far.

```
char *mystringtokenize(char **string, char delimiter) {
    static char *str = NULL;
    int stringIndex = 0;
    if (string != NULL) { //check if string is NULL, if its not null set str to string
        str = string;
    }
    if (string == NULL) { //return NULL if string is empty
        return NULL;
    }
    do { //traverse through string
        if (!str[stringIndex]) { //if str at string index is null character, stop while loop
            break;
        }
        stringIndex++;//index through string
    } while (str[stringIndex] != delimiter);
    
    str[stringIndex] = '\0'; //cut the string
    char *lastToken = str; //set last token to the cut off part
    
    return lastToken;
}
```

When I call it in `main`, and try to pass in the file that needs to be tokenized, I get a bad exception error.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE *inputStream = fopen("FitBitData.csv", "r");
    int index = 0;
    int fitbitindex = 0;
    char testline[100];
    char minute[10] = "0:00:00";
    FitbitData fitBitUser[1446];
    if (inputStream != NULL) {
        while (fgets(testline, sizeof(testline), inputStream) != NULL) {
            strcpy(fitBitUser[fitbitindex].patient, mystringtokenize(testline, ','));
            strcpy(fitBitUser[fitbitindex].minute, mystringtokenize(NULL, ','));
            printf("%s %s\n", fitBitUser[fitbitindex].patient, fitBitUser[fitbitindex].minute);
            printf("%s\n", fitBitUser[fitbitindex].patient);
            fitbitindex++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example, when I have a line `Hello, World` and tokenize it. It will return `Hello`. But If I call it again `mystringtokenize(NULL, ',')`, it returns a bad exception error.

Comment: Always read compiler messages. The compiler should issue a message for this     code snippet if(string != NULL){//check if string is NULL, if its not null set str to string
        str = string;

Comment: My advice, emulate strtok exactly first. Then modify your implementation to add functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the argument `string` should have type `char *`, not `char **`.
- `stringIndex` should have type `size_t`.
- the initial tests on `str` and `string` are incorrect and lead your code to always return `NULL` if the argument is null (this explains your segmentation fault).  You should instead use the `static` state `str` if the argument is null:

  ```
    if (string == NULL)
        string = str;
  ```
- the loop to find the delimiter is confusing too. You should use `strchr` or write a simple `while` loop:

  ```
    while (string[stringIndex] && string[stringIndex] != delimiter)
        stringIndex++;
  ```
- at the end of this loop, if you found a delimiter, store `string + stringIndex + 1` to `str` for the next call, otherwise store `NULL` to `str` so the next call returns `NULL`.

Here is a modified version:

```
char *mystringtokenize(char *str, char delimiter) {
    static char *state = NULL;
    
    if (str == NULL) {
        str = state;
        if (str == NULL)
            return NULL;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == delimiter) {
            str[i] = '\0';
            state = str + i + 1;
            return str;
        }
    }
    state = NULL;
    return str;
}
```

Note that this function does not implement the semantics of `strtok`:

- it takes a single delimiter character instead of a string of delimiters.
- it can return empty tokens: `",,"` will produce 3 empty tokens whereas `strtok` would return none.

Yet it still has the major flaw in `strtok`, ie: the hidden `static` state variable that prevents nested use of the function as well as makes it non thread safe.  You should accept an extra argument of type `char **` so this state variable can be provided by the caller as in `strtok_r`.

Here is a modified version using an external state and `strchr`:

```
char *mystringtokenize(char *str, char delimiter, char **state) {
    if (str == NULL && (str = *state) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    }
    char *p = strchr(str, delimiter);
    if (p) {
        *p++ = '\0';
    }
    *state = p;
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your function. The first one is that the first parameter shall have type `char *` instead of `char **`.

```
char *mystringtokenize(char *string, char delimiter);
```

If the first parameter is a null pointer then the function always returns `NULL`:

```
if(string == NULL){//return NULL if string is empty
    return NULL;
}
```

So for example such a call of the function

```
mystringtokenize(NULL,',')
```

does not extract a string.

The pointer `str` with static storage duration does not keep the last position of the extracted string between function calls.

The passed string can start from the delimiter. In this case your function returns an empty string.

Pay attention to that the function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to entered string. To remove the new line character `'\n'` you can write after a call of `fgets`

```
testline[strcspn( testline, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

If you are going to make your function similar to the standard C string function `strtok` then it will be useful to read the description of the function.

From the C17 Standard (7.24.5.8 The strtok function)

> 3 The first call in the sequence searches the string pointed to by s1
> for the first character that is not contained in the current separator
> string pointed to by s2. If no such character is found, then there are
> no tokens in the string pointed to by s1 and the strtok function
> returns a null pointer. If such a character is found, it is the start
> of the first token.

and

> 4 The strtok function then searches from there for a character that is
> contained in the current separator string. If no such character is
> found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to
> by s1, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null pointer.
> If such a character is found, it is overwritten by a null character,
> which terminates the current token. The strtok function saves a
> pointer to the following character, from which the next search for a
> token will start.

That is in particularly all characters that represent delimiters are skipped until a non-delimiter character is encountered. Otherwise the function returns a null pointer. It means that for example if the passed string is `",,"` and the delimiter is `','` then the function in its first call shall return a null pointer. Or if the original string is `",,,Hello,,,"` then in the first call the function shall return substring `"Hello"` and in a second call it shall return a null pointer.

It is important to note that the function shall never return an empty string.

Thus your function can be implemented for example the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * mystringtokenize( char *s, char delimiter )
{
    static char *p = NULL;

    char *substr = NULL;

    if (s != NULL) p = s;

    if ( p != NULL )
    {
        while (*p == delimiter) ++p;

        if (*p == '\0')
        {
            p = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            char *current = p;
            while (*current && *current != delimiter) ++current;

            substr = p;
            p = current;

            if (*p != '\0')
            {
                *p++ = '\0';
            }
        }
    }

    return substr;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = ",,,Hello,,, World!,,,";

    for (char *p = mystringtokenize( s, ',' ); p != NULL; p = mystringtokenize( NULL, ',' ))
    {
        puts( p );
    }

}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
 World!
```